# How to further shorten my training time on resnet-50 (pytorch 2.0)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training `resnet-50` with `CIFAR100` and soon with `ImageNet1k` (all `224*224` images). Training `ImageNet` costs a long time for me so I want to find some teniques to minimize the training time. I use `CIFAR100` first just to find the best trainging strategy. Here's my training details.

1. My device is a remote server, whose GPU is `NVIDIA A40`. It has `48G` GPU RAM, `80G` RAM and `12` vCPUs.
2. I used `pin_memory = True` and `prefetch_factor = 2` in my `DataLoaders`.
3. I used `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True` since the shape of my input tensors are fixed (`batchsize = 125, 250, 500 etc.` divides `50000`)
4. I used `torch.cuda.amp` in both training and evaluating periods (just `Grad_scalars()` and `autocast()`).
5. I used `torch.compile()` to accelerate my training, and `fullgraph = True, mode = 'max-autotune'`.
6. My loss function has two parts, mainly `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` (but not just only that).
7. Augmented data is included in my training. Transforms are `T.RandomCrop`, `T.RandomRotation` and `T.RandomHorizontalFlip`.

Based on these things, I shortend my training time a lot. Now training one epoch costs me about two minutes (originally five minutes). However, I want futher shorten training time like 1min/epoch since training `ImageNet` is costing. What can I do to acheive that as possible as I can? I know multiple devices can help but at present I think that's the last strategy I'll adopt.

Comment: In addition to enabling benchmark you can try to enable tensorcores:

torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = False
torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32 = True

Comment: @Bernhard Jaeger I tried these commands but found it become 10~20sec/epoch slower.